# Asus K55A Lubuntu not booting to OS. I think kernel update messed with ACPI somehow

Tags: boot, kernel, lubuntu

Here is PasteBin link using "journalctl -xd" command: https://pastebin.com/NAMjWvFB

How do I fix this?

```
sda      8:0    0 465.8G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0     1G  0 part /boot/efi
├─sda2   8:2    0  33.4G  0 part /
├─sda3   8:3    0     1K  0 part 
├─sda5   8:5    0   7.6G  0 part [SWAP]
└─sda6   8:6    0 336.5G  0 part 

Linux chris-K55A 5.0.0-27-generic #28~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Aug 22 03:00:32 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99465/discussion-on-question-by-hietertoboogy-asus-k55a-lubuntu-not-booting-to-os-i-t).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @guiverc you fix the partition where your Ubuntu OS (The GUI) is using the Fsck command or the Gparted application provided by Ubuntu or other favors if they have the app. Gparted uses an advance version of fsck called e2fsck which is a command-line app all on it's own.

You have to use a live disc (preferably the live disk you used to install your OS) to run these commands or the app.

For me my OS is in partition /dev/sda6/. If you're using Gparted right-click the partition -> Click 'Check' -> on the bottom of app right-click the 'pending' process and choose Apply. -> Let it run and finish (unless there is more errors) -> Shutdown your live OS -> Remove live disk -> Reboot. You should be able to boot to your OS GUI.